# IN Condition with comma separated values in a table-column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am facing one issue, when I am trying to pass column stored "comma separated values" to IN condition in my redshift SQL query.

Example:

### Table_Ref_parameters

PID   |  Parameter1
---     ---------------
1     |   P001,P002

### Source Table

ProductID   |    Description 
----------     ---------------
P001         |     P001_desc
P002         |     P002_desc
P003         |     P003_desc

--Query for selection from Source Table

select * from [Source Table] where ProductID in (select Parameter1 from Table_Ref_parameters)

--This does not give me any result, even I tried to give that with different quotations even in the column data like('P001','P002'). Still it does not work when I pass it through column.

Any one have any hint please help me out from this issue.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the in list needs to be a discrete set of strings. The select clause inside your in clause will generate one string for each row in table_ref_parameters. If you were to update your Table_Ref_Parameters so that each row contains one parameter without quotes, this will work fine.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. But I have different use of that table, I finally use that table to a pivoted view. So, I was looking for some dynamic approach as I can't fix for the number of values/columns. For now I am already using the technique you suggested.

Comment: In that case, you may be able to generate a sql script, prepare it for execution and execute it via the following commands. I havent tried this myself but may be worth a shot - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PREPARE.html, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_EXECUTE.html